# Module not found:Error can't resolve 'angular'

Tags: jquery, angular, angular5, angular6

I am using angular 6 to build website.Actually I want to run script on element when page is loaded.As angular ngOnit() runs script before content is loaded so I an getting problems.I found angular.element(function ()) that might solve this problem.but when I installed and imported angular into my project but I got error:
Error I got is:

> Error:Module not found:can't
>   resolve'../../../node_modules/@types/angular' in
>   'C:\Users\name\WebProject\src\app\sales'

I also imported it to my perticular component like this:

> import * as angular from '../../../node_modules/@types/angular';

My code to run script after content load is:

> ```
> ngOnInit() {
>        angular.element(function () {
>         alert('page loading completed');
>        });   }
> ```

It will be great if anyone help me out on thi or suggest me aany other way to achieve what I want.
Thanks.

Comment: Please add your error message to the question in text form, not as an image

Comment: paste your code which you have added...

Comment: `angular.element()` is AngularJS, Angular's predecessor, so that won't work. I don't understand yet why `ngOnInit()` doesn't work for you, that's the textbook place for running scripts when the element is used on the page.

Comment: ngOnit() does not work when I want to get attributes of any element in my layout.It just gets undefined.

Comment: ngOnit() executes before page is loaded or rendered.

Answer (score 0):

angular.element is AngularJS which is a totally different technology to Angular.

`ngOnInit` is too early in the component lifecycle.

Try using `ngAfterViewInit` instead like so:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  // code to run after view has initialised goes here
}
```